# get index and id of selected edittext for further processing

Tags: android

New to android and programming in general, so learning concepts as I go.

I have a LinearLayout to which I am adding edittexts dynamically.

I need to be able to get the Index AND Id of any edittext when it is selected or in focus.

I have tried looping through a child count to check for selected like so:

```
int count = llmain.getChildCount();
      for (int i=0; i< count; ++i) {
          if ((llmain.getChildAt(i).isSelected()) == true){
            //Do Stuff
          }
```

but I have no idea if its even close, and that would be only for index.....

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: still dont have a reliable way to achieve this. The example below with the

```
if(v instanceOf EditText) {
id = v.getId();
index = ll.indexOfChild(v);
```

returns a -1 for index and a ten digit number for the id, however, i am assigning an id on creation. ?The odd thing is that the code inside the "if" is running, so it at least thinks it has the focused view. Now, if I change the "instanceof" to a null check like

```
if (v != null){
            id = v.getId();
            index = llmain.indexOfChild(v);
```

AND I add a setFocusableInTouchMode(true), I get a proper return, however, it then acts like i called clearFocus(), because none of the EditTexts are focused. Here is my full proof of concept code that returns the correct values but no longer lets the EditTexts actually have focus.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&(event.getKeyCode() == 66)) // KeyEvent.* lists all the key codes u pressed
    {   
        View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.action, null);
        myView.setId(pos);
        pos++;
        myView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        llmain.addView(myView);
        myView.requestFocus();
        View v = llmain.findFocus();

        if (v != null){
            id = v.getId();
            index = llmain.indexOfChild(v);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "index is:" + index + "id is:" + id;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            }


    }
    return false;   
}
```

This returns the correct values unless I comment the setFocusableInTouchMode line, then it goes back to the odd -1 for index and ten digit for ID.   What am I doing wrong? going to have to be a good (and working) answer to get over half of my rep.....

So nobody has a solution for this? its still driving me nuts!

thanks again

Comment: Just a nitpick, the `== true` isn't necessary, you can just say `if(...isSelected())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial thought would be to set the ID equal to the index when adding an EditText, assuming only EditTexts will be in this particular layout:

```
LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llmain);
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
//0-based index, so get the number of current views, and use it for the next
editText.setId(llMain.getChildCount());
llMain.addView(editText);
```

Then, to retrieve the info, put a check into a listener of some sort (onTouch, onFocus, something like that):

```
@Override
public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
    int indexAndId = v.getId();
}
```

Give this a shot:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
int index, id;

//finds the currently focused View within the ViewGroup
View v = ll.findFocus();

if(v instanceOf EditText) {
    id = v.getId();
    index = ll.indexOfChild(v);
}
```

Comment: I was initially going to use something like this, but Im going to be inserting new edittexts randomly between others that are already there, so i would get repeating ID's, the Index would shift down, but the ID wouldn't, throwing everything off.

Comment: Ah okay. Well, can you describe how exactly you're going to be using the results of getting the ID and index? And where you'll be accessing it from? We could probably give you a better solution with more context.

Comment: well, the getting the index is so I can get its position in the view to insert a new one after it. the id is so I can refer to it uniquely for dynamic removal. example:   5 edittexts, one after another. I dynamically inflate a new edittext between #3 and #4, then I might delete #2 and its contents. then I might add one between what is now #1 and #3(which has become #2 in the index, but retains the same id)   does this make it clearer, im not always good at explaining myself?

Comment: Makes sense! I've added a new suggestion to my answer; I'm pretty sure it should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry to pull the check mark, but when i added the code it seemed to work, and I went on. Later I find out that it is miss reporting the index and id as a -1 and some ten digit number for id .... meaning its not finding the focused view, right?

Comment: Well, the 10-digit number for the ID sounds correct. As for the index, did you try stepping through with the debugger and making sure it's reaching the `indexOfChild` line?

Comment: Ashamed to say just learning to use the debugger, will report back with results. Thanks

Comment: Ok, after learning the debugger, and isolating the code, the debugger says the code is working correctly. even when i set an id however, it still returns the same thing....

Answer (score 1):

That seems like it would work to me, have you tested it and it isn't working?

`llmain.getChildAt(i).getId();` will return the views ID to you.

Comment: tested, tweaked, tested again..... I just dont seem to get anything to work reliably in giving me the id and index of the selected view (edittext). dont seem to be able to get any code working for something that seems like should be easier. your snippet does work to get me the id :)